# ASP.Net Application_BeginRequest & The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i have one country selection page from where user select country and a cookie is dropped in user pc as a result next user is redirected to page based on cookie value. so i check cookie exist in user pc from Application_BeginRequest and if not found then redirect user to country.aspx page

i debug the code and saw a infinite loop star. this way i code the whole things

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string sVal = BBAreman.CountryCookie.GetCookieValue();
            string xx = Request.Url.ToString();
            if (sVal.Trim() == "")
            {
                //Server.Transfer("~/index.aspx?ShowCountry=true",true);
                HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
                HttpContext context = application.Context;
                Response.RedirectPermanent("~/country.aspx?ShowCountry=true", true);
                //context.Response.End();
            }
}
```

i am in problem and not being able to think how could i solve this but i have seen server.transfer works but i saw when i use server.transfer then js related error shows in FF browser and just could not understand why js related error comes because when i reload that page manually then no js related error comes.

so just guide me how to solve this problem. also tell me is it possible to hook aspx page page load method from out side ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Application_BeginRequest isn't best place to run above code. 
Application_BeginRequest is application event called every time new page request starts.
By calling Response.Redirect... you create new page request which means that event fires again and again and again that's why you end up in infinite loop.

It's different with Server.Transfer as this method terminates current request on server side and returns response for new page (page you transferred to) so new request isn't created. Reason why you get js error must have something to do with how your page is implemented.

If you want to redirect user to particular page based on selection made last time user visited your site move your code to Session_Start event in the same class (Global.asax).

Comment: thanks for info....but can u plzz tell me when i use Server.Transfer then why js is related error comes but when i run the same page without Server.Transfer then no js related error occur.

Comment: Just like to emphasise the above answer by PrzemG. We had a project which had an infinite redirect loop bug after a server update. After some time finding the cause it was a Response.Redirect within the Application_BeginRequest() handler. Not a good location for redirect code.